# Remove clicked element, its parent and parent's previous element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove all elements below after clicking on the `p` element. Could you give me any pointers where am I going wrong?

```
<h2>Heading</h2>
<a href="#">
    <p>Click me to delete everything</p>
</a>

$('p').click(function() {
    $(this).remove().parent().remove().prev().remove();
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcAa9/1/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().prev().andSelf().remove();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BcAa9/3/)

[`andSelf` docs](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/)

`.addBack()` is an alias for `andSelf` that can also be used. The only difference is that `addBack` is only available in jQuery 1.8+, while `andSelf` is available since version 1.2.

[`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) are self-explanatory, [`andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) aka `addBack` simply adds the previous set of matched elements to the current set, that is, it combines `.parent().prev()` (the prev element of parent) with the previously executed `.parent()` (the parent element) and removes these in one go.

Answer (score 1):

After removing the `<p>`, it is indeed *removed from the DOM*. Therefore it has no parent anymore, and `.parent()` won't work. Instead, first select all elements, and *then* remove, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/BcAa9/4/.

```
$('p').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().prev().addBack().remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the only answer explaining why my own solution didn't work.

Comment: @finspin: Maybe it's helpful to look into the native (non-jQuery) way of removing elements. It would be something like `this.parentNode.removeChild(this)`, which more clearly shows that the element is detached from the parent, and that you hence cannot get its parent anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
<h2>Heading</h2>
<a href="#">
    <p>Click me to delete everything</p>
</a>
</div>
​
$('p').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcAa9/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest (assuming that you want to remove the previous sibling of the `a`:

```
$(this).closest('a').prev().andSelf().remove();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mDBxU/).

If you can wrap the elements in a container, it becomes easier:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <a href="#">
        <p>Click me to delete everything</p>
    </a>
</div>

$('p').click(
    function() {
        $(this).closest('.container').remove();
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mDBxU/1/).

References:

- [`andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to wrap everything in a div or span tag, and then use jquery's closest() function (http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find that parent element, and remove that. That will make your javascript code a little cleaner.

Comment: Good idea. Although, on the other hand, it will make my HTML code more messy ;)

Comment: True.  One thought that occurred to me though, is what if you want to add another element that needs to be removed?  You would have to add yet another link to that big chain of javascript functions, whereas with a parent element you just add it in and it will be removed.  May be irrelevant, but thats part of what affected my thinking there.

Comment: Actually, this will become relevant because I'll be adding more elements under the `h2` tag later on. Thanks, I learned something new today.